# Node js mongodb updating array with index in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoDB document, which, when in object form, you would access the desired array like this:

```
map.layers.1.data.INDEX
```

And this is what I currently have:

```
//Where = index, to = change to this
selector["data.layers.1.data."+where];
mDB.update({"_id":msg.island+msg.map}, {$set:{selector:to}} , function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});
```

(I made my map with [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/).)
Where data is an array, and I want to update just that one array index. But that index has to come from a variable. Is there a way to do this in mongoDB?

I'm currently reading whole document then replacing wanted data and then updating whole document. And that's not good, fast or necessary(I hope).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your description - an example document would be helpful - but I'll wing it. Assuming your documents look like

```
{
    "data" : {
        "layer" : [
            { "data" : [ 2, 5] },
            { "data" : [ 99 ] },
            { "data" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] },
            { "data" : [ -1, "truffles", 6 ] },
        ]
    }
}
```

then you could update a fixed index of the array `data.layer.2.data` stored as the value of a variable `myIndex` like so in the mongo shell (similar to node but synchronous, no callback)

```
var myIndex = complicatedprocedureforgeneratingtheindex() // myIndex = 1
var mySet = {}
mySet["data.layer.2.data." + myIndex] = to
db.map.update(myQuery, { "$set" : mySet })
db.map.find(myQuery)
{
    "data" : {
        "layer" : [
            { "data" : [ 2, 5] },
            { "data" : [ 99 ] },
            { "data" : [ 0, 99, 2, 3 ] },
            { "data" : [ -1, "truffles", 6 ] },
        ]
    }
}
```

Roughly (i.e. ideas are there but no copy paste b/c of undefined variables)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the answer!

In order to update an array with an given index, you have to define an object **seperately**, before the update:

```
set = {};
```

and then specify the index as a property of the object with [] embraces.

```
set['example.nested.object.' + i] = foo;
```

Then just update your MongoDB

```
Collection.update($set: set);
```

Should work.